# Interpretation deferment rate

Tags: geometric-brownian

Geometric Brownian motion related to house prices can be written as

$dH_t=(r-g)H_tdt+\sigma H_tdW_t$.

How should I interpret $g$?

The literature calls this a deferment rate. But I don't understand how this should be interpreted.  Should I interpret it as a kind of lost income people have by not letting or profit because they do not have to rent?

Comment: Is the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferment_rate) unclear?

Comment: To me it is. Should I interpret it as a kind of lost income people have by not letting or profit because they do not have to rent?